# attribute error in sklearn svm.SVC

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

having issues with attribute errors when implementing a linear SVM with scikit-learn. I'm using a linear classifier with cross-validation through the RFECV method, and I can't access any of the attributes of the SVC. Not sure if it has to do with the feature selection or base model.

```
    model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear')
    selector=RFECV(model)
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=pct_test)
    selector=selector.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    my_prediction = selector.predict(X_test)
    f1.append(metrics.f1_score(Y_test, my_prediction))
    kappa.append(metrics.cohen_kappa_score(Y_test, my_prediction))
    precision.append(metrics.precision_score(Y_test, my_prediction))
    recall.append(metrics.recall_score(Y_test, my_prediction))
    print model.intercept_
    print model.support_vectors_
    print model.coef_
```

Metrics work fine, attributes all fail. 
The error message is:

AttributeError: 'SVC' object has no attribute 'intercept_'

Documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC

Aside: I'm very new to OOP. If there's an underlying concept I'm missing, please elaborate or send over a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fitting (training the data) on the RFECV object `selector`, but trying to access attributes of SVC object `model`. But it is not trained. Hence there is no attribute `intercept_` in it.

To access the intercept of SVC, you should use:

```
selector.estimator_.intercept_
```

But understand that the above estimator is fitted only on the reduced dataset (After eliminating features as specified)

**Explanation:**

You see, RFECV internally uses [RFE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) to get important features in each iteration. And RFE clones the supplied estimator for the purpose. So when you initialize RFECV with `model`, it is trained on the clone of the model. 
Checking the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py):

Line 407 (inside the fit method of RFECV):

```
rfe = RFE(estimator=self.estimator, 
          n_features_to_select=n_features_to_select, 
          step=self.step, verbose=self.verbose)
```

Line 428 (for estimating the scores):

```
scores = parallel(func(rfe, self.estimator, X, y, train, test, scorer)
                       for train, test in cv.split(X, y))
```

And then Line 165 (Inside fit method of RFE):

```
estimator = clone(self.estimator)
```